# Is it possible to make an Nhibernate query generate columnName<>'value' rather than not(columnName='value')?)

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Is it possible to make an Nhibernate query generate Sql that has columnName<>'value' rather than not(columnName='value')?

I am told that using not() can have Sql performance issues over <>.

Typically I am writing my queries like this...

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.WhereNot<Region>(r => r.Id == region.Id));
```

which results in

```
WHERE  not (this_.RegionID = 2048)
```

UPDATE

This question suggests that there is no longer any performance issues with coding one way or the other

[In SQL Server is there any difference between not(columnName='value') and columnName<>'value'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816658/in-sql-server-is-there-any-difference-between-notcolumnname-value-and-column/8816799#8816799)

Comment: They should be optimized identically for any reasonable SQL product (certainly for SQL Server), so I'd challenge the assumption of a performance issue in the first place.

Comment: I think the option not available in criteria api.But you can use criteria.Add(Expression.Sql("columnName <>'value'"));

Comment: @an2 Yes that's a useful work around thanks. if you add it as an answer I'll accept it assuming that nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that option is not available in criteria api.But you can use Expression.Sql() as follow

```
criteria.Add(Expression.Sql("columnName <>'value'"));
```